# In Javascript, is there a way to create a copy-on-write clone of an object?

Tags: javascript, es6-proxy

Problem: I'm re-writing a function that returns a large plain javascript object. The original object should not be modified by callers. The function is currently called by hundreds of callers.

Some solutions:

- Return a deep copy of the object. This is the current solution. This is bad because (a) the object is very large, and (b) 90% of the time the clone is not necessary because the majority of the callers do not modify the value.
- Return a reference to the object. This is bad because callers will be able to modify the original object, which I do not want.
- Return a reference with `Object.freeze` or something similar. This might work if I could guarantee that callers don't attempt to modify the return value. But I can't feasibly guarantee this. Again, the function is called by hundreds of callers, and many already modify the (clone of the) value.

What I want is a copy-on-write solution that has the following two properties:

1. The return value of the function is a *reference* to the original object until the value is modified.
2. After the value is modified, it becomes a *deep clone* of the original object.

I did some tests and I can implement this using Javascript [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy). Simply trap on all operations that modify the target (i.e. `set`, `deleteProperty`, `defineProperty`, etc.) to listen for changes. Then trap on `get` to return a reference if no changes have been made, and return a clone if changes have been made. The proxy would also have to be a deep proxy to listen for changes on nested properties.

While I can implement this myself, I was wondering if there were any implementations already out there. I'd rather not re-invent the wheel if I don't have to. Browser compatibility is nice, but is not essential.

Comment: Looks like `cow` is what you need https://www.npmjs.com/package/cow

Comment: @artanik hmmm...this looks promising. Thanks!

Comment: Have u tried immer package

Answer (score 0):

The immer library doing exactly what you describe - implementing COW using JavaScript proxies.
Take a look at the docs here: https://immerjs.github.io/immer/